# VBA Macro that can find and scroll to cell with selected value in a ComboBox

Tags: excel, vba

I'm new to VBA and cannot figure out how to code for Excel VBA to find and scroll to a cell in my worksheet based on what I have selected from my ComboBox (or Drop down).

For context, I have a Workbook with Sheet1 and Sheet2. Sheet1 contains multiple different brands (rows) and I have a ComboBox in Sheet1 Cell A2 to select what brand I want. I want my Macro to scroll to my brand cell in Sheet1 based on the brand I've selected in my ComboBox, by finding the brand selected in Column B (my brand cell) of Sheet1.

I've tried coding this before but could not extract the value selected in my ComboBox, so what I did instead is to create a table of brands and its corresponding cellink value in Sheet2 and extract the value of the ComboBox by finding the cell link value in the table instead.

```
Sub Test()
Dim celllinkval
Dim brand As String
 
celllinkval = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet2").Range("C1")

brand = Application.WorksheetFunction.VLookup(celllinkval, Sheet2.Range("A1:B3"), 1, False)
 
Dim cell As Range
Dim Rng As Range

Set Rng = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1").Columns("B:B")
Set cell = Rng.Find(What:=brand, LookIn:=xlFormulas, LookAt:=xlWhole)

If Not cell Is Nothing Then Application.Goto cell, True

End Sub
```

this is my current code which I can't get to work, would really appreciate any help! Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not sure if you made a typo when trying to get the value of your combobox but this worked fine for me with the combobox named `ComboBox1`:

```
Sub Test()
    Dim brRow As Long
    Dim cbValue As String
    Dim cell As Range
    Dim ws As Worksheet
    
    Set ws = ActiveWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1")
    With ws
        cbValue = ComboBox1.Value
        brRow = Application.WorksheetFunction.Match(cbValue, .Range("B:B"), 0)
        'find the row to set the cell to
        Set cell = .Range("B" & brRow)
    End With
    
    If Not cell Is Nothing Then Application.Goto cell, True

End Sub
```

Hope this helps :)

Comment: Hello! It worked great! Thank you so much and I really appreciate your help!! :-)

For anyone else interested in this code, I only got it to work after clicking the ComboBox to view its code, so my first line is
Private Sub ComboBox1_Change()

Comment: Well you didn't mention it needing to be triggered on change as you were using Test(), figured you were checking the value/going to the cell after something else :)